# Java8 stream average of object property in collection

Tags: sorting, collections, java-8, average, java-stream

I'm new to Java so if this has already been answered somewhere else then I either don't know enough to search for the correct things or I just couldn't understand the answers.

So the question being:
I have a bunch of objects in a list:

```
try(Stream<String> logs = Files.lines(Paths.get(args))) {

        return logs.map(LogLine::parseLine).collect(Collectors.toList());


    }
```

And this is how the properties are added:

```
        LogLine line = new LogLine();
    line.setUri(matcher.group("uri"));
    line.setrequestDuration(matcher.group("requestDuration"));
    ....
```

How do I sort **logs** so that I end up with list where objects with same "uri" are displayed only once with average requestDuration.

Example:

```
         object1.uri = 'uri1', object1.requestDuration = 20;
         object2.uri = 'uri2', object2.requestDuration = 30;
         object3.uri = 'uri1', object3.requestDuration = 50;
```

Result:

```
        object1.uri = 'uri1', 35;
        object2.uri = 'uri2', 30;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [`Collectors.groupingBy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) and [`Collectors.averagingDouble`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingDouble-java.util.function.ToDoubleFunction-). In your case, you could use them as follows:

```
Map<String, Double> result = logLines.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        LogLine::getUri,
        TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.averagingDouble(LogLine::getRequestDuration)));
```

The `Collectors.groupingBy` method does what you want. It is overloaded, so that you can specify the function that returns the key to group elements by, the factory that creates the returned map (I'm using `TreeMap` here, because you want the entries ordered by key, in this case the URI), and a downstream collector, which collects the elements that match the key returned by the first parameter.

If you want an `Integer` instead of a `Double` value for the averages, consider using [`Collectors.averagingInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#averagingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-).

This assumes `LogLine` has `getUri()` and `getRequestDuration()` methods.